# Is the real scalar remained real after analytical continuation in imaginary time formulation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am studying [thermal field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_quantum_field_theory). I am being confused while studying analytical continuation of time coordinate made in the real scalar field theory at finite temperature. Apparently it occurs to me that the real scalar field would be complex one, but which is not possible otherwise the theory will contain double degrees of freedom. What I want to know, beside the analytical continuation in the imaginary time formalism, is the real scalar field analytically continued to real function of complex variable in the sense that it will map the complex variables to real number?  But for the real vector field the things won't be carried out same as for the real scalar field. The zeroth component of the vector field will change opposite to time component of the co-ordinate vector in analytical continuation.